# Advantage of multiple sitemap files

Tags: magento, sitemap

I am thinking about creating multiple sitemap files based on the top categories  for my magento website, I am just wondering what are the advantages of having multiple sitemaps for a website.

I know one limitation that google doesnt allow more than 50,000 url's in one sitemap file and size should also be less then 50MB.

Answer (score 1):

It will be definitely having advantages.

1) You can add more URLs in different sitemaps, so no worries regarding URL limits.

2) You can divide the sitemaps as per categories. e.g. if you have an electronic website, you can have mobiles.xml, homeappliances.xml, cameras.xml. This is a better approach, which will help google as well to collect your urls and index them more efficiently for SEO crowlings.